# How to get data from four tables from sql query in one query help me slove complex problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

here I have table '**bar_opening_details**' containing opening and closing stock and other details like closing date and table  '**bar_recvd_details**' contains data of purchase stock i receive.'**item_category**' has category names, table '**item_purchase_sales**' contains prices of items .
this is my SQL query what I wanted to achieve with this is wanted to list all values present on a given date i.e opening stock, closing stock, category name, item name, and stock purchase received for Items. problem opening and closing values are limited to the numbers of the received value in the table. items that do not have received purchase are not showing

```
SELECT 
   a.op_value, a.close_val, c.item_name, b.item_cat_name, a.op_date , a.close_date,d.recvd_value
FROM
   bar_opening_details a,
   item_category b,
   item_purchase_sales c,
   bar_recvd_details d    
WHERE
   a.item_id = c.item_id  and  a.item_cid = b.item_cid and d.item_id=a.item_id and  close_date="2019-06-18" and recvd_date="2019-06-18" ;
```

[image]

Comment: `sql-server` is Microsoft’s SQL Server. Because you have tagged this `phpmyadmin` (which is not a database) I’m assuming this is MySQL?

Comment: Combining multiple tables like this is usually done by JOINing them. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: its MySQL workbench

Comment: anyone can help me with this any help will be appreciated